# List the first few lines of every file in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to create a really simple bash script, which will list the first few lines of every file in a specific directory. The directory should be specified by the argument.
I think that the Grep command should be used, but I have really no idea how.

My existing script does not seem to work at all, so it's no use putting it in here.

Answer (score 9):

Use head command:

```
head -3 /path/to/dir/*
```

Answer (score 4):

For any answer using `head` and `*`, redirect stderr to /dev/null unless you want to see errors like:

```
head: error reading ‘tmp’: Is a directory
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in dir/*; do
    echo "-- $file --"
    head "$file"
    echo
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the first few lines of all files ending in `.txt`, try

```
head *.txt
```

or

```
head --lines=3 *.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Because bash does filename expansion (globbing) by default, you can just let your shell expand input and let head do the rest:

```
head *
```

The * wildcard expands to all the filenames in the working directory. On zsh you can see this nicely, when it autocompletes your commandline when you press tab.

You can change the amount of lines with the -n argument to head.

If you want to do this recursively:

```
find . \! -type d -exec head '{}' +
```